# how to create call function in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to create a button called (call) , when press this button calling the number that stored in it , and I don't have any code to use it

Comment: Can you re-write this entire question in a way that clearly explains what you want to do and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows phone, You can use [the launchers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769542%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Launchers).

Create a function for call a number is very easy :

```
string MyNumberPhone = "060000000000";

PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = MyNumberPhone ;
phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "UserName";
phoneCallTask.Show();
```

for this specific functionnality you can read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Also, for your application storage, You've a great [Nokia's tutorial here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/File_manipulation_with_IsolatedStorageFile_on_Windows_Phone) explain how to use IsolatedStorageFile, IsolatedStorageSettings and LINQ.

Comment: that's cool it's working good ...

Comment: please , I want to put 2 numbers when the phone dialing ask me which number call it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, can you explain me with more details please? thx.

Comment: I want to set two numbers for one name ... and display the two numbers when calling it and choose from the two number which num call it ...  could you help me please ?